# Передача параметров в ajax

Tags: ajax

Как правильно передать параметры в запрос.На данный момент данные передаются в таком виде

```
id:9
form:organization=1&department=Backend&manager=
```

Можно ли сделать что то типо

```
id:9
organization:1
department:Backend
manager:2




var btn = $(this);
        var form = btn.parents('form').serialize();
$.ajax({
                url : '/settings/create_department',
                method : 'POST',
                dataType : 'json',
                data : { id : depId, form},
                success : function(data){

                }
            });
```

Comment: а `depId` откуда берется? и почему её нельзя сделать в скрытом поле, чтоб она передавалась в `form` вместе с остальными? ...... если скрытым не хотите... можно пробовать `data : form.serialize() + "&id="+depId` и т.д.

Comment: Скрытое поле мне не совсем подходит в данной ситуации, а второй вариант как раз то что надо.Спасибо